# how to retrieve data from gridList in smartGWT

Tags: smartgwt

I have created a ListGrid from Smart GWT

Attached is the screenshot

I am not able to get the values of the gridList.

Attached is my gridList img

```
          ListGrid countryGrid = new ListGrid();
```

now how will i get this "my test" ?

thanks

[image]

Comment: Are you using DataSource of SmartGWT to fill up the grid?

Comment: this my test , is written by my self in the UI at run time ..

Comment: This is not the answer of my question. My question is : How do you fill up your grid? Are you using DataSource?

Comment: possible duplicate of [SmartGwt: how to fetch the data in my listgrid](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13487930/smartgwt-how-to-fetch-the-data-in-my-listgrid)