# SmartGwt: how to fetch the data in my listgrid

Tags: smartgwt

i have a list grid ,i am assiging the values to listGrid by some method in my app

like this

```
               private ListGridRecord[] getData(UserRecord selectedClient) { 

        return new ListGridRecord[]{  
                new NameValueRecord(1, "US Siren", selectedClient.getClientsId()),  
                new NameValueRecord(2, "EN: Liste des identifiants", selectedClient.getClientId2()),  
                new NameValueRecord(3, "Account number", selectedClient.getClientId3()),  
                new NameValueRecord(4, "Partner number", selectedClient.getClientId4()),  
                new NameValueRecord(5, "REGON", selectedClient.getClientId5()),  
                new NameValueRecord(6, "US Siren*", selectedClient.getClientId6()) , 
                new NameValueRecord(7, "TEST", selectedClient.getClientId7())  
        };  
    }
```

It works fine for me and shows the given values in the grid when the app runs .

Now i want to get these values which are displaying in the grid (Which user can also edit from the grid)

I can get the edited values like this

```
                clientIdsGrid.setEditorCustomizer(new ListGridEditorCustomizer() {  
            public FormItem getEditor(ListGridEditorContext context) {  
                ListGridField field = context.getEditField();  
                if (field.getName().equals("value")) {  
                    NameValueRecord record = (NameValueRecord) context.getEditedRecord();
```

But if a user dont even click on  any record and just click save to save the values as it is.

How can i then get the data which is in my grid .

I am trying these

```
                 clientIdsGrid.getRecord(1);
          clientIdsGrid.getRecords();
```

but this gives me a listGrid/listGridRecord , how can i then fetch the individual data on each row from them .

Comment: clientIdsGrid.getRecords() returns a ListGridRecord[] you can iterate with a for loop and each single ListGridRecord is one row displayed at your ListGrid. I can't understand what else you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`grid.addEditorExitHandler`  may help.  Within it u can use:

`grid.getEditValueAsString(row num, Column name)`  for getting new edited value.
If no new it will `return null`.